# AttributeError: module 'moviepy.video.fx.all' has no attribute 'speedx'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After converting a Video-Merger Python3 App to a Windows executable using pyinstaller, it does not launch, all it does is give me this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'moviepy.video.fx.all' has no attribute 'speedx'
```

The Moviepy module is imported and included in the code, I had other AttributeErrors like this one, but I could fix them by adding them manually in the **init**.py file, however, I am struggling with this one, not to mention, the app can be launched successfully when run in the command line.

Here's a screenshot of the full error:

[image]

And here's the video.fx **init**.py file:

```
import pkgutil

import moviepy.video.fx as fx

__all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
    fx.__path__) if name != "all"]

for name in __all__:
    exec("from ..%s import %s" % (name, name))


from moviepy.video.fx.accel_decel import accel_decel
from moviepy.video.fx.blackwhite import blackwhite
from moviepy.video.fx.blink import blink
from moviepy.video.fx.crop import crop
from moviepy.video.fx.even_size import even_size
from moviepy.video.fx.fadein import fadein
from moviepy.video.fx.fadeout import fadeout
from moviepy.video.fx.freeze import freeze
from moviepy.video.fx.freeze_region import freeze_region
from moviepy.video.fx.gamma_corr import gamma_corr
from moviepy.video.fx.headblur import headblur
from moviepy.video.fx.invert_colors import invert_colors
from moviepy.video.fx.loop import loop
from moviepy.video.fx.lum_contrast import lum_contrast
from moviepy.video.fx.make_loopable import make_loopable
from moviepy.video.fx.margin import margin
from moviepy.video.fx.mask_and import mask_and
from moviepy.video.fx.mask_color import mask_color
from moviepy.video.fx.mask_or import mask_or
from moviepy.video.fx.mirror_x import mirror_x
from moviepy.video.fx.mirror_y import mirror_y
from moviepy.video.fx.painting import painting
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize
from moviepy.video.fx.rotate import rotate
from moviepy.video.fx.scroll import scroll
from moviepy.video.fx.supersample import supersample
from moviepy.video.fx.time_mirror import time_mirror
from moviepy.video.fx.time_symmetrize import time_symmetrize


__all__ = (
    "accel_decel",
    "blackwhite",
    "blink",
    "crop",
    "even_size",
    "fadein",
    "fadeout",
    "freeze",
    "freeze_region",
    "gamma_corr",
    "headblur",
    "invert_colors",
    "loop",
    "lum_contrast",
    "make_loopable",
    "margin",
    "mask_and",
    "mask_color",
    "mask_or",
    "mirror_x",
    "mirror_y",
    "multiply_color",
    "multiply_speed",
    "painting",
    "resize",
    "rotate",
    "scroll",
    "supersample",
    "time_mirror",
    "time_symmetrize",
)
```

Comment: Did you try `from moviepy import *`?

Comment: @grumpyp, if you mean (from moviepy.editor import *), yes I did.

Comment: maybe it needs some `C/C++` library and `pyinstaller` didn't find it and it didn't add it to .exe file. You may need to figure out what library it may need and add it manually to .exe using configuration file `.spec`. Read all documentation for `pyinstaller`

Comment: it seems it uses `exec()` to import all files .py in folder `video/fx/` - and there is file `speedx.py`. `pyinstaller` may not recognize imported file - and you may have to manually add all there files to `.spec` . See: [Using Spec Files — PyInstaller 5.4.1 documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)